# How to remove handles from this faucet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, faucet

[image: leaky faucet]

I am trying to replace the washer on this leaky faucet. There are no visible screws or removable caps anywhere on this faucet. I have already tried to pry the top part of the handle off and tried to to turn the top part CCW while holding the base still to no avail. I have also tried pulling really hard.

Does anyone have this same model or know something I don't? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The picture really helps, but knowing the manufacturer and model number would help even more.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I don't know that. It came with the house.

Comment: Is there a set screw (Allen head) perhaps on the back side?

Comment: Most likely the valve is a cartridge and not an old fashioned soft washer pressing on a metal seat. If you can get it apart, you would take the cartridge out and see if you could get a replacement. Is the leaking side the hot or the cold?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a screwdriver just below the handle and twisting? Maybe two screwdrivers, one on each side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that the lower skirt just below the faucet handle is threaded onto part of the fixture that comes up from the bottom side of the sink. Have you tried rotating the skirt to see if it would untread?

Comment: Michael, are you suggesting that unscrewing the skirt would force off the handle? that the handle is just a press fit?

Comment: @JimStewart - I have no idea. It is possible that the handle is built as part of the skirt where they can rotate with respect to each other but still be attached to each other. As you can see I posed it more as a suggestion to try. There are just too darn many faucet designs in the world to be able to be 100% sure about any given one.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you Michael.

Comment: Awesome. Glad that this set you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to uninstall the faucet and separate the valve sides from the plate.

Then the valve covers under the handles will be removable - remove them at this point it will now be apparent how the handles are removed as you will have access to the handles retaining mechanism in order to remove them.

Comment: Wow! If one has to uninstall the faucet to change the cartridge, then the faucet was intended to be replaced when the cartridge would fail. I would guess that this faucet was very cheap, maybe 1/5 the cost in bulk of a an old fashioned heavy brass Price-Pfister domestically made unit which by modern standards is over engineered and wasteful of material. Is the delivery end on  a flexible hose so it comes out to use to rise the sink.

Comment: @JimStewart Sometimes they are engineered to be consumables.